# Не тянутся элементы в Adobe Dreamweaver

Tags: dreamweaver

При работе в режиме дизайна в программе не тянется div. От чего это зависит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`div` будет растягиваться, если вы укажете ему атрибут `position:absolute;`, тогда при растягивании дополнительно в стиле вашего `div` будут изменяться атрибуты `width: --px; height: --px;`

Comment: Спасибо, бро.
Лови лойс.

Comment: Нет, не лови.
У меня репутация маленькая.

Comment: я не бро, я сестренка)) Пожалуйста.

Comment: Вот теперь, лови, сестренка.